# android listView row height

Tags: android, listview, height, row

I implemented a listview with 2 kinds of rows from here [listViews with multiple rows tutorial](http://logc.at/2011/10/10/handling-listviews-with-multiple-row-types/)

all is working properly,

the problem that I have now is setting the height for the rows,

if I leave the background as a color, all is good,

but if I use an image for background, I only get a tall row [on other simple list views the height respect the programatically set height], but in this case, the row changes

so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/category_item_row"
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:background="#ff00ff"
  android:layout_height="70dp"
  android:padding="3dp"
 >

<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/image"
 android:layout_width="40dp"
 android:layout_height="70dp"
 android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/title"
 android:textSize="20sp"
 android:layout_width="90dp"
 android:layout_height="70dp"
 android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

works fine,

but

```
android:background="@drawable/phone_cat_cell">
```

is not respecting the assigned  height,

how to fix this height using my image background?

thanks!

edit 1, adapter

```
listViewItem.setAdapter(new PhoneItemAdapter(new ItemPhoneDataSource().getItems()));

private class PhoneItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  
    final List<RowPhone> rows;//row

    //data source, style
    PhoneItemAdapter(List<ItemPhone> animals) {
        rows = new ArrayList<RowPhone>();//member variable

        //choose cell! iterator
        for (ItemPhone item : animals) {
            //if it has an image, use an ImageRow
            if (item.getImageId() != null) {
                rows.add(new RowFolderPhone(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()), item)); //imageRow!
            } else {//otherwise use a DescriptionRow

                rows.add(new RowItemPhone(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()), item));                   
            }
        }
    }

    //delegate
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return RowTypePhone.values().length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        //con cast
        return ((RowPhone) rows.get(position)).getViewType();

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return rows.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //cambiado con cast!
        return ((RowPhone) rows.get(position)).getView(convertView);
    }
   }
```

Comment: Can you post your adapter method?

Comment: @Beginner I placed the adapter thanks

Comment: you want set a different background for each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to make not static images, but "9patch" images.
All android versions are supporting that.
Have a look here http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: hi, nine patch fixed it, but couldnt make it with the sdk tool, all good with the online tool http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html

Comment: yep 9 patch was added not in first android version thats why we need to use 3rd party apps to make this images

Answer (score 3):

Check your adapter code, if you are passing null while inflating the view then please replace that code with this.

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, parent, false);
```

Comment: hi , thanks, I tried // ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_folder_phone, null);
         ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_folder_phone, (ViewGroup) view, false); but doesnt work either, tnx

Comment: Hi, In custom list view I have to change image size dynamically, for every row there are different size of image need to display, imageview height will not change, I have try above code, It not working for me, is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```